# Is there an infinite group generated by the elements of two (or more, but finitely many) normal subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

It's perfectly easy to get an infinite group generated by the elements of a finite set of finite subgroups:  take a free product.

But is it possible to have an infinite group be generated by the elements of a finite set of finite *normal* subgroups?  If so, I'd be interested either in a general construction yielding such groups or an interesting example or two.

Comment: No, finite normal subgroups always generate a finite normal subgroup.

Answer (score 4):

If $H$ and $K$ are subgroup of $G$ and if one of them is normal, then $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$. So if they are both finite, they generate a finite subgroup.